# How to implement a security layer over .net WS?

Tags: .net, esb, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm running the latest WSO2 ESB and I was wondering how can I implement a security layer over the existing .NET web services?

Through a proxy service maybe? Kinda lost with all the extensive documentation.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could host the existing .Net web service on the WSO2 Carbon ESB by including the Service Hosting OSGi component in the ESB.  You then create an endpoint to the .net WS in the ESB. Now create a proxy for the endpoint within the ESB. The ESB is now "front ending" the .Net WS so you can use the mediation capabilities of the ESB to implement your security layer (there are many options for this).

Comment: I managed to find it and completely forgot about this question.
Thanks anyway mate

Comment: Hi Hal, can you suggest some resource or tips about how to do this, I want to implement the same thing.

Comment: Hello I cannot find anywhere the "Service Hosting OSGi component in the ESB", can you provide me a link? thanks a lot